.Net Core - Windows server hosting - what is running?
I have installed in my server this version of windows server hosting

And I believe this is used by the IIS, per example, to run applications built in .net5.
Correct me if I am wrong.
But now I need to uninstall this and use the .net6  core version.
How to know what is running in the .net 5 and how to migrate them to .net 6?
Thanks
